# git rebase squash messes up branches history

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-squash

I have a `git` repository with a long history and various branches, which have been merged into `master`. However, the first commits simply stem from the first one, without any branching.

I would like to squash together some of these first commits. To do that I did

```
git rebase -i --root
```

then in the editor I selected the commits to squash, then changed the commit message for the squased commits. `git rebase` seems to work fine, but to my surprise, `git log` shows that the history has been messed up, losing the history of branch merging: several commits appear now duplicate, and branches are unmerged.

Although it is difficult to replicate the full problem, here I provide a minimal example that shows a similar issue. Consider a `git` local repository created by the following commands

```
git init .
touch foo.txt
git add foo.txt
for (( i=1; i<4; i++ )); do echo hello $i >>foo.txt ; git commit -a -m $i; done
git checkout -B test
for (( i=1; i<4; i++ )); do echo hello $i >>foo.txt; git commit -a -m test$i; done
git checkout master
git merge test
for (( i=4; i<5; i++ )); do echo hello $i >>foo.txt ; git commit -a -m $i; done
```

This creates a repository, after some commits a new branch `test`, which is then merged into `master` (simple fast-forward), and finally a last commit on `master`.
The log of the repository is (Author/Date removed)

```
git log --graph --all

* commit ba326e1ada9525fd2b1b275c597ad189b7cf3ddf (HEAD -> master)
| Author: 
| Date:   
| 
|     4
| 
* commit b739356170f946f3d1b3c3cb3299f4379212ecc6 (test)
| Author: 
| Date:   
| 
|     test3
| 
* commit 303e95fd23beb9c5a96c631667dfd2be7e924390
| Author: 
| Date:   
| 
|     test2
| 
* commit dd67e3ca5f12e35c736483bcc8335347dc78da87
| Author: 
| Date:   
| 
|     test1
| 
* commit 2420498ae794fa900dd9fee8296b7561e08028b8
| Author: 
| Date:   
| 
|     3
| 
* commit 2d43d89d2b75566f37a99b7cce294cddcd3fbf7a
| Author: 
| Date:   
| 
|     2
| 
* commit 487e5158e461479f848eb7313dc87090f197f4a7
  Author: 
  Date:   

      1
```

Now, I squash the commits "2" and "3" into a single one. I do

`git rebase -i --root`

and in the editor I enter

```
pick 487e515 1
pick 2d43d89 2
squash 2420498 3
pick dd67e3c test1
pick 303e95f test2
pick b739356 test3
pick ba326e1 4
```

In the commit message for the squashed commit I enter "squash 2 3".
`git rebase` seeems to finish well:

```
[detached HEAD b5d1682] squash 2 3
 Date: Mon May 13 12:01:19 2019 +0200
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
```

However, to my surprise the history is a mess now

```
git log --graph --all

* commit 463cbb99f553d555fadbe05a3cc90aeb46b0bbce  (HEAD -> master)
| Author: 
| Date:   
| 
|     4
| 
* commit 194e78fc74d4eaea62a8b903baa6379dfc8578d3
| Author: 
| Date:   
| 
|     test3
| 
* commit 8f5e0be6dd8288790b2893e9b3fa97e5e1021134
| Author: 
| Date:   
| 
|     test2
| 
* commit 1060aea0f3da5dfee8e37adc68d82d77e7c02ba4
| Author: 
| Date:   
| 
|     test1
| 
* commit b5d168283be820fed3b9862576c44c054402ab50
| Author: 
| Date:   
| 
|     squash 2 3
|   
| * commit b739356170f946f3d1b3c3cb3299f4379212ecc6 (test)
| | Author: 
| | Date:   
| | 
| |     test3
| | 
| * commit 303e95fd23beb9c5a96c631667dfd2be7e924390
| | Author: 
| | Date:   
| |
| |     test2
| | 
| * commit dd67e3ca5f12e35c736483bcc8335347dc78da87
| | Author: 
| | Date:   
| | 
| |     test1
| | 
| * commit 2420498ae794fa900dd9fee8296b7561e08028b8
| | Author: 
| | Date:   
| | 
| |     3
| | 
| * commit 2d43d89d2b75566f37a99b7cce294cddcd3fbf7a
|/  Author: 
|   Date:  
|   
|       2
| 
* commit 487e5158e461479f848eb7313dc87090f197f4a7
  Author: 
  Date:   

      1
```

`git rebase` has split again the merged `test` branch, while the `master` branch retains the history. However, I have also lost the information that `test` was merged in `master`.

I expected a history like that:

```
git log --graph --all

* commit ba326e1ada9525fd2b1b275c597ad189b7cf3ddf (HEAD -> master)
| Author: 
| Date:   
| 
|     4
| 
* commit b739356170f946f3d1b3c3cb3299f4379212ecc6 (test)
| Author: 
| Date:   
| 
|     test3
| 
* commit 303e95fd23beb9c5a96c631667dfd2be7e924390
| Author: 
| Date:   
| 
|     test2
| 
* commit dd67e3ca5f12e35c736483bcc8335347dc78da87
| Author: 
| Date:   
| 
|     test1
| 
* commit 2420498ae794fa900dd9fee8296b7561e08028b8
| Author: 
| Date:   
| 
|     squash 2 3
|
* commit 487e5158e461479f848eb7313dc87090f197f4a7
  Author: 
  Date:   

      1
```

Is this a bug of `git rebase`? I am using git 2.19.2

If I try without the branch `test` or if I delete the branch `test` before rebasing, it works fine and produce the desired history, but still I lose the information on the `test` branch.

Moreover, in more complex cases, where `test` is merged without a simple fast-forward, deleting the `test` branch before a squash with `git rebase` produces apparently a full loss of the merged branch history.

The following example illustrates this point.

```
git init .
touch foo.txt
git add foo.txt
for (( i=1; i<4; i++ )); do echo hello $i >>foo.txt ; git commit -a -m $i; done
git checkout -B test
for (( i=1; i<4; i++ )); do echo hello $i >>foo.txt; git commit -a -m test$i; done
git checkout master
touch foo2.txt
git add foo2.txt
git commit -a -m 4
git merge test
git branch -D test
```

Now the log history is

```
git log --graph --all

*   commit e905116fed7f4d52c65da46ab6172ae7a08e824a (HEAD -> master)
|\  Merge: 77cc483 584a037
| | Author: 
| | Date:   
| | 
| |     Merge branch 'test'
| | 
| * commit 584a03768822ebd92d4feee20ebe238fffd89c25
| | Author: 
| | Date:   
| | 
| |     test3
| | 
| * commit 7a2ad09b5c39e5076cd22fa957c2d539e37c0861
| | Author: 
| | Date:   
| | 
| |     test2
| | 
| * commit 11ef4fea5ba207a637a85d8e8456f48d0c7bd7ab
| | Author: 
| | Date:   
| | 
| |     test1
| | 
* | commit 77cc4833cf5aac84aca9737945fd79a7632019ac
|/  Author: 
|   Date:   
|   
|       4
| 
* commit 081792ccf9b4714ab4bce23e4e7b126647eeead8
| Author: 
| Date:   
| 
|     3
| 
* commit 971f217200f7e485308b861033b5b31b7ae69d1a
| Author: 
| Date:  
| 
|     2
| 
* commit cef186ae9ad0e316d82c62c2082381747f25a443
  Author: 
  Date:  

      1
```

Merging together the commits 2 and 3 as above, produces the a repository with the following log

```
git log --graph --all

* commit 3a4010551d50a47a9db6d53a4597770fa2517d92 (HEAD -> master)
| Author: 
| Date:   
| 
|     test3
| 
* commit bbbc747780c847b3d40ed7557ed514e5e4dd9fc2
| Author: 
| Date:  
| 
|     test2
| 
* commit 6f54fd90555fbe6730fcfe7d85761b6477380214
| Author: 
| Date:   
| 
|     test1
| 
* commit 71fa7371198a0cbbf4793dc27ffb27ac65d15096
| Author: 
| Date:  
| 
|     4
| 
* commit 3032069c375ef37b42af75c97759d7a821f1139f
| Author: 
| Date:   
| 
|     s 2 3
| 
* commit cef186ae9ad0e316d82c62c2082381747f25a443
  Author:
  Date:  

      1
```

The logs shows that I have lost the history of branching and merging of the `test` branch. If did not delete the `test` branch after merging it into `master`, I obtain a similar results as the first example, with a split branch `test`.

Comment: Rebasing a master branch is almost never a good idea. It rewrites history and causes issues when merging branches into master. Please checkout https://devtales.net/article/git-rebase-is-like-fire

Comment: That's actually the normal desired result of rebase (desired by whom, is a good question, though :-) ). Very recent Git versions have a fancier `--rebase-merges` mode that can handle more complex scenarios, but yes, filter-branch is a more appropriate tool. Just be aware that no matter how you do this, you're making a whole new history, which once made, should never be re-combined with the original history: in essence you're making Git repositories that should never meet again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After realising that `git rebase` is not the right tool, I have devised a solution based on `git filter-branch`. The idea is to alter the commit "2" adding the content of commit "3" via a patch. Then, commit "3" becomes empty, hence it can be eliminated.

Considering the second example.

```
git diff 971f217200f7e485308b861033b5b31b7ae69d1a \
         081792ccf9b4714ab4bce23e4e7b126647eeead8 \
         >patch.txt
git filter-branch --tree-filter '\
   if [ "$GIT_COMMIT" == "971f217200f7e485308b861033b5b31b7ae69d1a" ]
   then
       git apply /localdirectory/patch.txt
   fi' \
   --prune-empty -- --all
```

Since `git filter-branch` works in a temporary subdirectory `.git-rewrite/t`, the `git apply` command requires a full path for the patch file.

This leaves some old refs. After checking that the `git log` is correct, a cleanup can be done

```
git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master
```

This gives a repository with log

```
git log --graph --all

*   commit e905116fed7f4d52c65da46ab6172ae7a08e824a (HEAD -> master)
|\  Merge: 77cc483 584a037
| | Author: 
| | Date:   
| | 
| |     Merge branch 'test'
| | 
| * commit 584a03768822ebd92d4feee20ebe238fffd89c25
| | Author: 
| | Date:   
| | 
| |     test3
| | 
| * commit 7a2ad09b5c39e5076cd22fa957c2d539e37c0861
| | Author: 
| | Date:   
| | 
| |     test2
| | 
| * commit 11ef4fea5ba207a637a85d8e8456f48d0c7bd7ab
| | Author: 
| | Date:   
| | 
| |     test1
| | 
* | commit 77cc4833cf5aac84aca9737945fd79a7632019ac
|/  Author: 
|   Date:   
|   
|       4
| 
* commit 971f217200f7e485308b861033b5b31b7ae69d1a
| Author: 
| Date:  
| 
|     2
| 
* commit cef186ae9ad0e316d82c62c2082381747f25a443
  Author: 
  Date:  

      1
```

At this point the task is essentially done. Still, it could be useful to change the message for the commit "2". This can be done with the msg-filter, for instance:

```
git filter-branch --msg-filter 'sed "s/^2/2 and 3 together/"' -- --all
git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master
```

In case there are more branches, like in the first example, one needs to eliminate also the corresponding old refs, e.g.:

```
git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/test
```

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: `rebase` only rebases a single branch.

A rebase is only performed in the current branch (or the one specified by argument). Thus, your results are just as expected, since you only rebase the `master` branch, and the `test` branch remains the same, i.e. its `HEAD` points to your old commits.

If you read the [git rebase doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) carefully, you will see that it always talks about `the current branch`.

If you want other branches pointing to the rebased commits, you will have to `reset` them. In this case, checking out `test` branch and  using `git reset --hard 194e78fc74d4eaea62a8b903baa6379dfc8578d3` would lead to the result you expected. (As always, be careful using `reset --hard`, as it will delete uncommited changes.)

I do not understand what information you fear to loose, since all changes of branch `test` are present in the rebased history of `master`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Resetting branch ```test``` may works in the example above, but on more complex histories, with non-fast-forward merges of branches you lose information. I have added another example in the question.

Comment: Take a look at the [`--preserve-merges` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---preserve-merges): rebase is, by default, "flattening [the] history by replaying commits a merge commit introduces". thus, the merge commits are lost, but the commits they introduce are kept. So, the command you're looking for might be `git rebase -i --preserve-merges`.

Comment: Note that the "loosing information" you speak of is not "loosing contents of commits", but "loosing merge commits". More precise: You do not loose code, but meta-information about your repositorys history, like which branch was merged where.